# How to test crashes in Android for multiple devices?

Tags: android, testing, crash, crashlytics, stability

We are using Fabric for tracking crashlytics. Daily we receive crash report, those are related to specific devices.

My question is how to avoid crashes in Android, if it is occurred how can I test it. Because most of the crashes are related to Device specific and Network Specific.

- Is there any tool to identify and test crashes before it is moved to
  production.
- Is there any way to test app in different devices for different functionalities.

Comment: There are testing services such as Cloud Test Lab that let you perform tests on a variety of devices before you publish.  You really should be writing instrumentation tests to fully automatically test your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about Android crashes in general, we have to consider that exists a lot of things that can affect its behavior, and than cause a Crash.

I will list to you, what I consider to be good pratices to avoid crashs.

1 - Write Unit tests

2 - Write tests with Test automation framework like Appium

3 - AWS Device Farm. (With your Automation script, you can put your apk and your test automation script in AWS Device Farm and select which Android device and version you want to use. )

4 - Use a CI (Continuous Integration) to never forget to run your tests and do things that are important to your application =) ([http://www.bitrise.io](http://bitrise.io) is a good solution for this)

And always try to stay updated of android news versions

Answer (score 0):

Some SDK is available to find and help to resolve  crashes in app Like Crittercism, Crash analytics  of fabric, which give you crash detail show you can find exact location and crash in your app. Both are free.
And I am suggesting fabric is good for it.